# Aggregate of a certain field for previous dates of the month in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

So, let's say I have a table with just id, date, and sales. I want a laravel eloquent query that shows the accumulated sales so far for that date for the month. For example:

What I want:

| ID | Date | Sales | Acc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 100 | 100 |
| 2 | 2020-01-02 | 50 | 150 |
| 3 | 2020-01-03 | 200 | 350 |
| 4 | 2020-02-01 | 220 | 220 |
| 5 | 2020-02-02 | 300 | 520 |

The above table is what I want from Eloquent, the actual table is without Acc.

I don't want to create a new column, I just want to show the accumulated through the eloquent query. Thank you!

Comment: Kindly add the expected result just like the added table.

Comment: Ah the actual table is without the ACC, I want it with the ACC. Thank you! @ruleboy21

Comment: So if it were me... I'd just do your normal eloquent call with a date range using a wherebetween  then loop over the collection and total the amounts as a variable to sent to the front.  You can also do this as a running total from a collection too by mapping ACC into the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is not clear if you have a model already, but you mention you want to use eloquend. Let's assume you have a model called Sales. In your controller:

```html
$sales = Sales::all();

$accTotal = $sales->map(function($sale){
   $add += $sale->acc;  
});

return $add;
```